# Select first, next sibling :not() matching a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've looked through other Q&As but didn't find this particular example. (Please point me to it if I missed it)

I have no control over the HTML which looks like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="group open"><td>stuff</td></tr>
  <tr class="child"><td>stuff</td></tr>
  <tr class="child"><td>stuff</td></tr>
  ditto
<tr class="group"><td>stuff</td></tr> //Style this one only
<tr class="group"><td>stuff</td></tr>
//etc.
</tbody>
</table>
```

(Yes, the ".child" name is not really accurate here; not my code.)

Is it possible to style the first next tr.group sibling that isn't a tr.child? There could be any number of tr.child elements after the tr.open one.

I tried this with no success:

```
div.mystuff table tr.group.open + tr:not(.child)
```

The only thing I can add is that the tr.child elements are set to display:none on load. But this shouldn't affect styling on display:block.

Comment: And where are your `td`s?

Comment: In "stuff"; trying to keep things simple.

Comment: Can you post your complete HTML?

Comment: The full page is gigantic. Do we need the tds+content to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Will `tr.open` always be there and always be the first child? Or, at least, will `tr.open` always be the first `tr.group` if not the first child? Regardless, will there only ever be one `tr.open` at a time?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like their code permits any number of trs to be .open. Makes things tricky.

Comment: Whenever there's a `tr.open`, will there always be at least one `tr.child` following it? Sorry if I'm asking too many questions - CSS selectors are finicky about structural details like that :)

Comment: Yes, all tr.groups have at least one tr.child following, otherwise they are set to tr.atomic. Does that help? (Finicky! You're telling me!)

Comment: @cbmtrx: Yes it does - that eliminates the need to have a certain entire selector (specifically, `div.mystuff table tr.group.open + tr.group`). Anyway, since the existing answers aren't helping when they should, try debugging those scripts and, hopefully, updating your question with whatever you can find.

Comment: Yup. I reckon there's a hidden .js function controlling this. Not a deal-breaker but will post more info if I solve it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
div.mystuff table tr.child + tr.group { /* your styles */ }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NdqJk/)

Comment: So simple! This one SHOULD work, but it doesn't. Which leads me to think that there is some background jQuery/javascript preventing it. Beyond my control...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
div.mystuff table tr.group.open ~ tr.child + tr.group {
   color: sky;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emtZC/4/

Comment: Trouble is the number of tr.childs is unknown :/

Comment: Right, that should have done it. Still doesn't work. My guess is there's something else superseding this behavior.

Comment: I can't; it's gargantuan. There are 5000+ lines of CSS in just one file, and multiple CSS and .JS files loaded. I'm editing CSS in the last-loaded doc but clearly something is taking precedence over this styling.

Strangely, it **will** style those following tr.child elements, just not the next tr.group.

Answer (score 1):

### Not Possible By CSS Alone

***If you were dealing with only one open element***, then it could work: [**see this fiddle for a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/emtZC/16/) of this code:

```
.mystuff table .open ~ .group { /* select all */
    background: #ffff00;    
}
.mystuff table .open ~ .group ~ .group { /* revert all but first */
    background: #aaaaaa;    
}
```

But with multiple `.open` elements, or with not overriding the code even if there were only one, the issue is that you will still have other `.child` elements in the code, but undisplayed. However, them being undisplayed has *no bearing on selection* ([see Adrift's answer with hidden children](http://jsfiddle.net/emtZC/15/) and [my answer failing with multiple children](http://jsfiddle.net/emtZC/35/)). It is this usage of the undisplayed `.child` elements still for selecting that is the "superseding" behavior you are seeing in your actual case of many rows (and many hidden children); it has nothing to do with javascript overriding (as your comments indicate you suspect), its just the way CSS adjacent and general sibling selectors work.

I believe your only solution will be through javascript, [here is a jquery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/emtZC/46/) (changing background color):

```
$('.open').each(function(index) {             
    $(this).nextAll('.group:not(.open)').first().css('background', '#ff0') 
});
```

Comment: This will fail once there's more than one `.open` though.

Comment: I must have missed that there could be more than one `.open` (too many comments to read through).

Comment: Yeah... that was mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950854/css-select-first-next-sibling-not-matching-a-class/#comment26234408_17950854) but it was buried by my comments, so I've voted it up to bump it into view now. It could have been edited directly into the question instead though, but oh well.

Comment: Well, that bites. I'll leave my explanation as to why the other answers (and now mine if more than one are `open`) are not working, and then give the only solution I know of: to use some form of javascript.